# How to save converted text data from azure cognitive services?

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I'm currently having a hard time saving the result of the speech to text from Microsoft azure cognitive service API.

This is my code.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time

# Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
# Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
speech_key, service_region = "speech_key", "region"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

# Creates a recognizer with the given settings

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region, speech_recognition_language="it-IT")
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('\nSESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('\n{}'.format(evt.result.text)))

print('Say a few words\n\n')
result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
print(result.text)

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
time.sleep(10)
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

speech_recognizer.session_started.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.recognized.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.disconnect_all()
```

I wanted to save the converted text from speech-to-text API. I already had a subscription key and region, but have no clue how to save the data to JSON file.

Comment: save your "result.text" to a file

Answer (score 0):

The [result.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.recognitionresult?view=azure-dotnet) returns the recognized text in the result, you can save to the file.

In Python this repo added some sample code to demo the Speech to Text SDK:
https://github.com/caiomsouza/Microsoft-Cognitive-Services/tree/master/speech-to-text and this python [code](https://github.com/caiomsouza/Microsoft-Cognitive-Services/blob/master/speech-to-text/speech-to-text-all-files_large_files.py) is converting any audio files size.